# Get responses from plugin while executing with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Sorry because this post is duplicate with some. But my english is limited to read a hard post's content, and i am a new javascript too.
assume in my plugin has a funtion will does a loop from 1 to 100. It will be run when i click in a button and handle by ajax like this:

```
//I dont need paste full JS codes, because it worked
jQuery.ajax({
           url  : ln_ajax_handle.ajax_url,
           type : 'post',
           data : {
                action    : 'ln_ajax_handle',
                main_data : json_data
            },
            success : function(result){
                jQuery('#ln-modal-bangchinh').html(result);
            }
       });
```

Ok, now we will look in my php function

```
function ln_ajax_handle(){
    $data = $_POST['main_data'];

    for($i = 1; $i <= 100; ++$i){
        echo $i . $data . '<br>';
    }

    wp_die();
}
```

I can get results when the loop is done. but, i want after `$i + 1`, `echo`  will show to web page while the loop is executing. Because in real time, i need handle lager datas, and better if i can check result when one of them was done.
Please help me a simple example. Thank you!

Comment: you'd need output buffer flushing in PHP. But this is unreliable when done via ajax, and it is difficult to make it work in all circumstances, unfortunately.

Comment: As an alternative, if each loop takes a long time, you could make multiple ajax requests which fetch, say, 10 results each time, so that your page has the impression that it loads gradually. The ajax call would pass to the server the numbers of the items it wants to fetch each time.

Comment: Can you help me a simple example about call ajax multiple ?  i don't know a bout that technical

Comment: you can just use a loop to make the same call multiple times, but with different values each time for the item numbers. Does that make sense? Sorry I don't have a lot of time right now to write anything out in full.

Comment: your mean is a loop in js file, not php?

Comment: yes that's what I mean. ajax is started from the JS in the browser, so to make multiple ajax calls, then it's fairly easy to see that the loop must be in the JS part. Your PHP would need a change as well, to only output the items requested. P.S. I assume the example you've given above is theoretical or incomplete? I ask only because it does no useful work - it just outputs whatever was input into it.

Comment: Thank you about your exprirences. it just my things in this time. i have not writen php codes to do this.